# PHP Qmail piping to script not working due to permissions?

Tags: php, email, piping, qmail

I have Qmail set up to pipe to a script for a particular email address, which is working; However, part of the script creates a file which is not working.

The group on the folder it is attempting to write to is `apache` with write permission (775). I have added `popuser` to the apache group, confirmed by `id popuser`. This may be unnecessary, based on the info below. (I have tried making apache both the primary/effective group, and secondary)

I've used `get_current_uid()`, `getmyuid()`, `getmygid()`, `exec("whoami")` inside the PHP script:

`get_current_uid() = [file/folder OWNER] (we'll call him Bob, he is a user not a group)`

`getmyuid() = Bob`

`getmygid() = Bob`

`exec("whoami") = [blank]`

If I set the directory I want to write to to 777, everything works fine - implying permissions are the cause. The files, in this case are owned, and have the group of `popuser` (which is not the result of the uid/gid bits above). This would imply, to me at least, that the current user is actually `popuser` and not `Bob`.

As a result, I can chmod to 0644, but cannot chown/chgrp (I need apache to be the group, as another UI elsewhere allows for managing files).

In an attempt to not have to make the directory world-writeable, I have stuck a `chmod('/path/to/dir', 0777);` in before the file is created and `chmod('/path/to/dir', 0775);` after, but this is apparently running as `popuser` also as it fails.

What I need to do, in a nutshell, is create a file in the directory that `Bob` / `apache` (owner / group) have write permissions to using qmail which says it is running as `Bob`, but actually runs as `popuser`.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: My workaround for now is to have a separate directory that is owned by Bob with popuser as the group. Create the file using that directory, invoke another httpd process using file_get_contents to read the file, then write to the correct directory, then on the original script delete the temporary file.

Not my favourite.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I am entirely following what you are saying.  However, it is possible to pipe incoming mail into qmail to a script running in any user's directory, and for that script to create a file.

If you've not done so already, add a line in /var/qmail/control/rcphosts to tell qmail that it should be acting as the MX for your domain.

In /var/qmail/control/virtualdomains, add a line like so to tell qmail which user account to route mail to for this domain:
    domain.tld:username

create a .qmail-default file in user directory, containing a pipe to the script that you want to route the mail to:
    | /path/to/script

restart qmail.

You'll need to grant execute permissions for all on the script.  Then, the script should be able to create new files, when triggered by an incoming email.